# Interpolation of velocities on staggered grid (in PIC)

Tags: finite-difference, interpolation, navier-stokes, grid

**Edit:** (*copying from my comment*)

Let's consider the inverse problem when I need to transfer velocities from particles to the grid (inverse bilinear interpolation). How'd I transfer a particle's x-velocity to the velocities located at cell's face in the Q region? Would the particle's velocity be distributed among the 2 face-velocities (as opposed to 4 face velocities in non-boundary locations)?

---

I'm implementing staggered grid for a [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) simulation (pressures in the center of a cell, velocities on faces) and I'm trying to find out how to interpolate the velocities. To simplify my problem, let's consider the 2D case;

[image: PIC staggered grid]

- red dot = pressure (irrelevant to my question)
- blue bar = the x-axis component of velocity
- green bar = the y-axis component of velocity

If I was to implement the grid based on the above image, I'd store 3 arrays:

- `3x4` array for the (blue) x-velocities
- `4x3` array for the (green) y-velocities
- `3x3` array for the (red) pressures

The problem with these array's sizes is interpolation of velocities at the grid boundaries – imagine you'd want to interpolate the (blue) x-velocity (from the `3x4` array) for particles that are located in the lower half of the bottom cells (the lower half of a cell is the part of the cell, that is below the blue bar representing x-velocities - *take a look at the second image below – it's the area marked as `Q`*).

When I'd want to interpolate the x-velocity in the center (non-boundary) cells, everything would be OK – I'd choose 4 nearest (blue) velocities for a given position in the grid and based on the 4 velocities, I'd bilinearly interpolate the velocity.

**However, when I'd try to interpolate in the lower-half of the bottom cells, I'd no longer have 4 velocities to interpolate from – only the 2. The interpolation would degrade from bilinear into linear!** (And I suppose that's incorrect implementation of staggered grid interpolation.)

---

The obvious fix would be to store the velocities on grid's **verticies** instead of on faces. The velocity for a face could then be linearly interpolated from 2 neighboring verticies when needed. **Is this the conventional/preferred/best way how to solve interpolation of velocities on staggered grid?**

[image: Velocities stored on verticies, the face velocities are interpolated when needed.]

- green bars = x-velocities stored on grid's verticies
- orange bars = linearly interpolated x-velocities from 2 green bars
- yellow points = the sample point for which velocity needs to be interpolated
- `Q` = the lower(upper)-half of the bottom(top) cells
- `A` = the sample point in the `Q` region

Comment: Aren't there boundary conditions at the boundaries that can be used for the interpolation?

Comment: @AbhilashReddyM Thank you for pointing me to the right direction - I'm just starting with PIC, so I don't know a lot of (basic) stuff yet. I have another question: let's consider the inverse problem when I need to transfer velocities from particles **to** the grid (inverse bilinear interpolation) - should I also utilize boundary conditions? How'd I e.g. transfer a particle's x-velocity to the velocities located at cell's face in the `Q` region? Would the particle's velocity be distributed among the 2 face-velocities (as opposed to 4 face velocities in non-boundary locations)?

Comment: Sorry. I don't actually work with PIC methods.

Comment: @AbhilashReddyM OK. I'll update my question to include the inverse problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fluid->particle problem, @AbhilashReddyM gave you the answer, the boundary condition will give you the value of $v_x$ at the boundaries.

For the particle->fluid problem, yes, it is *a* boundary condition that you need to use, but not necessarily the one of your fluid problem: e.g. if particles are allowed to slide/roll against the boundary while the fluid obeys no-slip condition, then you have a different BC for each.

Note that for clarity, you should have asked questions separately.

Comment: Could you please explain the `"particle's x-velocity component"->"staggered grid"` conversion at boundary? Consider [this grid](http://i.imgur.com/rlIhwfo.jpg)'s cell `[2,1]`. There's a particle `b`. It has (pink) velocity `v_b`. `v_b` has x-velocity component called `v_bx` (purple). How do I transfer `v_bx` to the staggered grid (the grid is represented by the orange bars on cell's faces). Do I just split `v_bx` via linear interpolation between `gx_2` and `gx_3`? If not, how would a boundary condition help me? *(to be continued)*

Comment: *(continuing)* AFAIK in PIC, there's BC stating that the velocity component normal to the boundary should be 0 - which seems to be fullfilled in the case of particle `b`'s x-velocity component: the cell that `b` is in has boundary normal perpendicular to both `gx_2` and `gx_3`. So how can such a boundary condition help me to splat `b`'s velocity to the grid? Thank you.

Comment: The p->f problem can be understood as a form of linear regression from point data to an interpolant of velocities of particle phase at your points gx_i and (for your "Q region") at the boundary. So the BC is crucial to define this interpolant.

Comment: Let's say I have the slip condition defined - now, I don't understand how this BC could help me in the case of [particle `b`](http://i.imgur.com/rlIhwfo.jpg). *Can you please state a concrete example how `v_bx` would be transfered to the grid?* (I obviously tried to google this problem up, but I've seen no **concrete** definition of how to do the particle->grid interpolation at boundary. For example take a look at page `21` of [this PDF](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~c2batty/teaching/general/Fluids2.pdf) - there's stated how to interopolate velocity at the interior cells, but not at boundaries.)

Comment: Slip condition means symmetry with respect to the boundary, as simple as this.

Comment: OK, so for example: given the Slip condition and particle `b`, I'd distribute `v_bx` between `gx_2` and `gx_3` via simple linear interpolation. Is that true?

Comment: That's the idea. I must warn that you didn't give enough detail of the problem your solving for me to judge on the whole of the scheme.